# Node.js + Socket.io Realtime game - keeping track of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, real-time

I am making a realtime puzzle game using Node.js and Socket.io in the backend and Angular in the frontend. I need to keep track of time that the user spends on the puzzle and send it to the backend once they complete the puzzle OR if the time runs out before. I am not sure what the best approach for this would be.

My initial thought is just to keep track the time on the client side, which is easy to do. I would then send the time once the user completes the puzzle OR the time runs out. I think this would not be very secure since the client can easily slow down their computer or do something else to send false data.

My other idea is to just keep track of the time on the server side for EACH socket/player. I would also have to update the client side by emitting a message to the client after every second or something. This way is definitely secure because the client would never send me the time information. But this approach has other issues, how would this scale?

My last idea is to use a combination of both techniques. For example, I'll have a counter on the client side that shows the client the time so I don't have to make the server "emit" a time message every second or something. I would keep track of the time on the sever side, and simply use that information to update the score etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The third option definitely sounds best to me. Since you're using Node on the back end, you get access to setTimeout just like you do in the browser. You can use that to schedule an event to be emitted to the client when their time is up, and meanwhile use front-end code to display the time remaining. You'll just want to make sure you don't start the clock on the front end until you've received confirmation that the timer has started on the server, and maybe pad the server timeout slightly to ensure that you don't cheat your player out of any time if things gets slightly out of sync!

Answer (score 0):

Your third option is definitely the best. The only question is: how precise does it have to be? I don't know if people are going to compete for high scores based on time, but it would suck if higher latency would lead to a worse time. Personally I believe you could accept this for puzzle games, because it would otherwise become quite complicated. One solution for this could be to initially accept the (possibly tainted) client side measured time, but check it with the server time with a certain margin (+/- 1 second for example).

Answer (score 0):

I fully understood what you were going to implement
I think you must implement the tracking in server, not frontend
As you know, the users can send the fake request
So in this case, you can use the websocket method
If you use the websocket method, we can check the user's played time
For example, we know when users start and end the game
so I think you can count the while time
I hope the websocket method is good way for you
Thanks